# How can I create the empty json object?

Tags: python, json

I have this code

```
json.loads(request.POST.get('mydata',dict()))
```

But I get this error

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

I just want that if don't have `mydata` in POST, then I don't get that error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simply:

```
json.loads(request.POST.get('mydata', '{}'))
```

Or:

```
data = json.loads(request.POST['mydata']) if 'mydata' in request.POST else {}
```

Or:

```
if 'mydata' in request.POST:
    data = json.loads(request.POST['mydata'])
else:
    data = {} # or data = None
```

Comment: One snafu here that often catches people is the empty string. If mydata is empty, then this will fail and the default argument in the get won't save you.

Answer (score 1):

[`loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) takes a json formatted string and turns it into a Python object like dict or list. In your code, you're passing `dict()` as default value if `mydata` doesn't exist in `request.POST`, while it should be a string, like `"{}"`. So you can write -

```
json_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('mydata', "{}"))
```

Also remember, the value of `request.POST['mydata']` must be JSON formatted, or else you'll get the same error.